# Replacing values in dataframe to nan when greater than x?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace values in a column to NaN. I normally use

```
imputed_data_x = imputed_data_x.replace(0, np.nan)
```

But my problem is that my values are not exactly 0, some are 0.01111,etc.  How can I replace all values in a data frame that is less than 1?

I tried `imputed_data_x = imputed_data_x.replace(>1, np.nan)`

But it didn't work. I'm curious to see if I can use replace to do this or do I need a different command for conditions?

Comment: np.where() may help here

Comment: `imputed_data_x.mask(imputed_data_x.lt(1))` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use standard [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
imputed_data_x[imputed_data_x < 1] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.replace` is just for replacing fixed values. In your case you want to replace if the value is "close" to 0 which you can express as a predicate function. The API command to replace a value where the predicate returns **false** (keep the value where it is true) is

```
imputed_data_x = imputed_data_x.where(lambda x: x >= 1, np.nan)
```